# Vert.x mqtt server 3.6.0 is MQTT Version 5 compliant?

Tags: vert.x

From the vert.x documentation(https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mqtt/java/#_vert_x_mqtt_server) its clear that Vert.x Mqtt Server is not a full fledged broker, is it MQTT 5 compliant or just 3.1.1 .

Answer (score 1):

It's only MQTT 3, but PRs are more than welcome!